# Automatic actions by makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have written simple code *make_test* to test the functionality of makefile. The folder structure is as follows:

1. include folder contains ***maths.h***

   ```
   float add(float a, float b) 
   {
       return a+b;
   }
   ```
2. the main file contains the following code:

   ```
   # include <stdio.h>
   # include <include/maths.h> 

   int main(int argc, char** argv) 
   {
       float a=1; 
       float b=4; 

       printf("%f + %f = %f\n", a, b, add(a, b));
       return 0;
    }
   ```
3. The makefile which contains the following:

   ```
   IDIR = -I.
   DEPS = ./include/maths.h
   CC= gcc -Wall -g $(IDIR)

   program: make_test.o

   %.o: test/%.c $(DEPS)
       @echo "Rule 1 was called"
       $(CC) -o $@ $<

   %.o: test/%.c $(DEPS)
       @echo "Rule 2 was called"
       $(CC) -o $@ $<

   %.o: test/%.c $(DEPS)
       @echo "Rule 3 was called"
       $(CC) -o $@ $<
   ```

Note that there are test/%.c statements that have been deliberately inserted for testing. 
There is no test folder. If I make a change in main file and I type make on the command line, I get

```
    gcc -Wall -g -I.    -c -o make_test.o make_test.c
```

My question is that I have not added -c flag anywhere then why does it appear at the output? Shouldn't there be a "Nothing to do" output because no dependency either exists (test/%.c) or is changed (include/maths.h)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make contains a large number of built-in rules.  You can see them by running something like this: `make -p -f /dev/null`.  One of these rules is being used to compile your code, and it contains the `-c` flag.

Why is a built-in rule being used?  Because your rules you defined do not match.  They tell make how to build a `.o` files from a `.c` file in the `test` subdirectory.  But the `make_test.c` file is not in the `test` subdirectory, so those rules can't be used by make.  Thus make looks at its built-in rules to find a rule that can build a `.o` from a `.c` in this same directory, and finds one, and uses that.

If you  move your `make_test.c` file into the `test` subdirectory, then your rules will be used.

Note, though, that make is correct here: you must add the `-c` flag to the compiler invocation if you want `.o` output.  Your rules will not create an object file, they'll create an exectuable named `xxx.o` which is pretty confusing.